# How to see what objects have been garbage collected in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Please, is there any way how to get history of objects (their variable or at least class names) that have been garbage collected in Java?

Just adding these params (to Oracle JVM)

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

doesn't provide anything else memory in bytes. It's very limited help to me. Thanks for all responses.

Note: Workaround with add finilize() method is not unfortunatelly an option for me (I don't have an access to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: My company develops the tool that I recommend in this answer.

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) you can go to the "Recorded objects" view in the memory section and switch the liveness mode to garbage collected objects (View->Change Liveness Mode->Garbage Collected Objects). You will then see a statistics of objects that have been GCed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. JProfiler looks awesome but 450€ is too very expensive

Comment: Is there any way to list down the classes programmatically? I was going through the java.lang.Management package but it can return count only.

Comment: You mean in JProfiler or in a JDK MBean?

Comment: How do I record memory from JVM start? - The UI forces me to click on a button - but my program runs only for 5 seconds

Comment: @Hurda In the dialog that is shown when you start a profiling session, you can configure an initial recording profile.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `finalize` method from `Object`. This method is called when the object is about to be GCed. From here, you can log the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for a memory leak?

If you implement `finalize()` method (available in every `Object`) it will get called just before the object is being garbage collected - and you can run any code inside it.

If you are looking for a systematic solution (or you don't have access to classes you want to monitor), I am not aware of any JVM option that allows that. However you *can* log classes being loaded and unloaded (GCed), but this is not what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference#Java) or [phantom references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_reference) seem to be useful to log when the object actually gets removed. In [this article](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references#heading-17171) the technology is explained.

Answer (score -2):

There is a nice built-in tool in JDK for observing jvm in runtime. It is jvisualvm. There is a a good reference with screenshots: http://visualvm.java.net/description.html

Here is one of them :
[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: jprofiler is a very powerful and common used tool but it is free only for opensource and the standard license for single instance costs real money - $500. It might be a problem for some projects.

Comment: I know and using VisualVM but it doesn't support to see garbage collected objects.

Comment: That is a useful tool, but it doesn't answer this particular need.